# ¿Cómo resaltar un texto en concreto dentro de un TextArea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

Tengo un formulario con un *textArea* en el que tengo pensado que la gente pueda nombrar a otras personas mediante un *@*, entonces había pensado en hacer una validación del texto conforme se va escribiendo en el *textArea*, de tal forma que cuando un usuario escriba el *@*, el método de validación lo detecte y lo pinte de un color en concreto.

Lo que he probado es mediante una expresión regular, ese texto cumpla las condiciones para ser remarcado, y modifico el la palabra poniéndole una etiqueta  con la clase que me interesa.

El método es el siguiente:

```
commentToSendFormatter(comment: string): string{
      let words = comment.split(" ");
      let finalString = "";
      words.forEach(word => {
        if (word.charAt(0) === "@" && word.length > 1) {
          let match = word.match(keys.ctrl_instagram_pattern);
          let lastCharacters = word.replace(match![0], "").replace("@", "");
          finalString += `<p class="txt-red">@${match![0]}</p>${lastCharacters} `
        } else {
          finalString += word;
        }
      });
      comment = finalString;
    return comment;
  }
```

Después, le quiero dar al text area el valor de ese comentario final, pero si por ejemplo pongo `Hola @Maricarmen`, lo que me sale en el *textArea* es `Hola <p class="txt-red">Maricarmen</p>`.

He probado a usar lo siguiente:

`$("#comment").val(--texto modificado--)`

Y el resultado es el anteriormente mencionado. También he probado a usar:

`$("#comment").html(--texto modificado--)`

Dado que le estoy insertando un texto con etiquetas de *HTML*, pero no funciona.

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Comment: Aclaración: el elemento a añadir es `<span>` y no `<p>` (el span es en línea, esto es, no introduce altos de línea, mietras que el p es elemento de bloque, esto es, ocupa otra línea distinta).

Por otro lado, en un textarea, a menos que trabajes cómo se muestra el html o tengas un editor WYSIWYG, en principio es correcto el resultado que te da, ya que estás introduciendo texto en un elemento que muestra texto.

Comment: Bueno sí, sé que es con ```<span>```, todo eso lo he hecho a modo de prueba. Entonces no puedo insertar en el textArea texto con html para que lo interprete, no?